# How to close one of several opened projects in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I have opened 2 projects in one PyCharm window. Projects are dependent.

When I close and then open one of the projects, the other one opens too. Even after I removed the dependency.

How to detach them now? How to close one of the projects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Deleting a project from view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-multiple-projects.html#d170568e224):

> If you want to close a project that has been added to the currently
>   opened one (primary project), follow these steps:
>
> 1. In the [Project Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html), right-click the project to be deleted.
> 2. On the context menu of the selection, choose **Remove from Project View**, or just press `Delete`:
>
> [image]

You might find the entire [Opening Multiple Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-multiple-projects.html) of interest.

Comment: If 'Remove from Project View' is not on the context menu, check that you have 'Project' selected from the scopes dropdown menu at the top, not 'Project files' or anything else

Comment: I have "Project" selected and the option "Remove from project view" still does nothing. Pressing Delete also does nothing. What to do?